# Laravel Queues - Dispatch Array of Jobs

Tags: laravel, message-queue

I need to push hundreds of jobs onto a queue, and my rabbitMQ server lives on a different machine, so the network latency really adds up (e.g. 0.01s latency * 300 jobs => 3 seconds).

Is it possible to push an array of jobs onto a queue?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248634/laravel-5-bulk-queue-jobs-w-same-data)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using RabbitMQ so I can't use the DB example